# Overriding Kotlin's property setter leads to two JPA @Id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have three Kotlin's classes representing Hibernate entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Parent {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(nullable=false)
    var id: Long? = null
}

@Entity
class Child1 {}

@Entity
class Child2 {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(nullable=false)
    override var id: Long? = null
        set(value) {
            super.id = value
            doSomething()
        }
}
```

Note I need to override the setter for `id` to call `doSomething` afterwards. That is the way I had id done in Java before.

It builds correctly, but Hibernate does not like it:

```
A foreign key refering Child2 from ... has the wrong number of column. Should be 2.
```

From some other error I suspect the overriden `id` is not correctly overriden and Hibernate sees the `id` columns twice - from `Parent` and `Child2`.

Comment: Do you really need to add annotations on the overridden version of `id`? (Did not tried myself)

Comment: I tried that as well, but then it leads to: `Repeated column in mapping for entity: Child2 column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally found a solution:

```
override var id: Long?
    get() = super.id
    set(value) {
        super.id = value
        doSomething()
    }
```

The trick is:

1. not assigning a value to the field
2. creating a getter linking to the `super`

This way Kotlin will not create a new field on the entity and it will just override the getter/setter.